# Trying to change background of JTextPane during runtime, succeeding but with errors

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextpane

So I have a `JTextPane` object that needs to change it's background to that of a specific image during runtime. What I have seems to be quite buggy (`JComboBox` used to change the background and call `repaintBackground()` doesn't seem to autoclose on selection, etc), it also throws a nullpointer and I have no clue why as the background changes.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintSafely(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthEditorPaneUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthEditorPaneUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
etc etc etc....
```

This is my object:

```
public class PreviewPane extends JTextPane  {
    private String _name = "bg3";   

    public PreviewPane() {
        super();
        setOpaque(false);
        StyledDocument document = this.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        document.setParagraphAttributes(0, document.getLength(), center, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)  throws RuntimeException{
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        BufferedImage img = null;

            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("/icons/"+_name+".png").toURI()));
            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }

         g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);


        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public void repaintBackground(String bgName){

        _name = bgName;

        paintComponent(this.getGraphics());

    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)  throws RuntimeException{
 .. img = ImageIO.read(` Whoa!  A paint method: 1) Should not throw a run-time exception. 2) Should immediately call the super method. 3) Shouldn't attempt a potentially long running task like loading an image!

Comment: How would you recommend going about avoiding this?

Comment: Which 'this'?  Be specific.

Comment: Getting rid of this whole NullPointerException, which doesn't even make sense to me since the background img is obviously found. Or do you have a better way to change a JTextPanel background (with an image) during runtime?

Comment: Ach!  It gets worse..  `} catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
.. //e.printStackTrace();` this code is now deliberately ignoring exceptions.  Further, if it failed to load the image, it should not proceed to `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);`..

Comment: *"the background img is obviously found."*  Why do you presume that?  The code is ignoring exceptions.  **Uncomment this line:**  `//e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Uncommenting the line makes no difference. The img is obviously found because, the JTextPane seems to change background accordingly during runtime. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `paintComponent(this.getGraphics());` - **NO**. You should never have to explicitly call `paintComponent`. Instead call `repaint()`.
2. `super.paintComponent(g);` should be called at the *beginning* of the `paintComponent` method, or at least before you do any painting in with the `Graphics` context.
3. Don't load your images in the `paintComponent` method. One option is to keep a cache in a `Map<String, Image>`. That way you can easily refer to them, without having to load them each time you want to change. Overall it's not *that* huge of an issue, whether you decide to cache them or not. You can just load it in the `repaintBackground` method.
4. Keep a class member `Image image;`. This will be the `Image` you use to paint. Your `repaintBackground`, I would have it accept an `Image` instead of a String. The `Image` you pass will the class member `Image image` that is used for the painting. You could still have the method accept a String, if you decide to load the image from that method.

   ```
   classs MyPanel extends JPanel {
       Image image;

       public void repaintBackground(Image image) {
           this.image = image;
           repaint();
       }

       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           g.drawImage(image);
       }
   }
   ```
5. `paintComponent` should not throw a `RuntimeException`

Here's a complete example. I decided to go with the `Map` cache. It up to you how you want to do it. There's many ways you can handle this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageChangeDemo {

    private ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();

    public ImageChangeDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(imagePanel);
        frame.add(createCombo(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JComboBox createCombo() {
        String[] items = {
            ImagePanel.DIRECTORY,
            ImagePanel.COMPUTER,
            ImagePanel.FILE,
            ImagePanel.FLOPPY,
            ImagePanel.HARD_DRIVE
        };
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items);
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                imagePanel.repaintBackground(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
        });
        return comboBox;
    }

    private class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        public static final String DIRECTORY = "directory";
        public static final String FILE = "file";
        public static final String COMPUTER = "computer";
        public static final String HARD_DRIVE = "harddrive";
        public static final String FLOPPY = "floppy";

        Map<String, Image> images = new HashMap<>();

        private Image currentImage;

        public ImagePanel() {
            initImageMap();
            repaintBackground(DIRECTORY);
        }

        private void initImageMap() {
            ImageIcon dirIcon = (ImageIcon)UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon");
            ImageIcon fileIcon =(ImageIcon)UIManager.getIcon("FileView.fileIcon");
            ImageIcon compIcon = (ImageIcon)UIManager.getIcon("FileView.computerIcon");
            ImageIcon hdIcon = (ImageIcon)UIManager.getIcon("FileView.hardDriveIcon");
            ImageIcon flopIcon = (ImageIcon)UIManager.getIcon("FileView.floppyDriveIcon");
            images.put(DIRECTORY, dirIcon.getImage());
            images.put(FILE, fileIcon.getImage());
            images.put(COMPUTER, compIcon.getImage());
            images.put(HARD_DRIVE, hdIcon.getImage());
            images.put(FLOPPY, flopIcon.getImage());
        }

        protected void repaintBackground(String key) {
            currentImage = images.get(key);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(currentImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(150, 150);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new ImageChangeDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all separate image initilizing and drawing. Move the img loading out of paint. Also don't try to create file. If the image in a JAR file could not be created.

```
public PreviewPane() {
    super();
    setOpaque(false);
    StyledDocument document = this.getStyledDocument();
    SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.setParagraphAttributes(0, document.getLength(), center, false);
}

BufferedImage img = null;

private void initImg() {
    if( img==null) {
        img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icons/"+_name+".png")));
//process missing img here
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)  throws RuntimeException{
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    initImg();

    BufferedImage img = null;

     g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);


    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Comment: This is loading the image inside paintComponent too ;)

Comment: This also still seems to give me exceptions :)

Comment: @Stefan just for the first time and of course it could be moved out into e.g. constructor

Comment: @user3421980 post SSCCE to reproduce the problem